# How to iterate through Linked List

Tags: c#

I have looked around and I can't really find an answer I can understand or it doesn't apply to me. I have this class:

```
class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node next;
}
```

And I have a member variable called `head` which is the head of the single linked list. Now I am trying to iterate through the different nodes of the linked list to search for a specific `value`. I know if I do it manually then I would do `head.next.next.next.next.value` if I want the `value` of the 5th node. This would quickly get tedious for a linked list of very large size so my question is **how can I create some loop to iterate through this so that I can check the `value` variable in each node of the linked list?**

Comment: Surprised to see no one suggested using a foreach below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You iterate through your class as follows:

```
var currentNode = head;
while ((currentNode != null) && (currentNode.Value != desiredValue))
   currentNode = currentNode.next;
```

When the `while` loop completes, currentNode will be `null` or contain a node with the desired value.

Comment: Just because you posted faster :) Everyone has the answer I was looking for but your's is slightly more detailed since it also includes the desiredValue that I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old post, but this is what is popping up on google, and I do have a good alternative to the current best answer (not including the desired value condition)

```
LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
for(LinkedListNode<T> node = list.First; node != null; node=node.Next){
    //do stuff
}
```

This version obviously uses a for loop and moves the variable declaration and increment to one line allowing you to condense and beautify your code.

---

**Later Edit:** If you wish to make your own Linked List (for whatever reason, *cough cough*), try this:

```
// assumed implementation of class
LinkedList myLinkedList = new LinkedList();

int searchForValue = 5; // origial poster wants to search for value
Node resultNode = null;
int resultIndex = 0;
for(Node iNode = myLinkedList.head; iNode!=null; iNode = myLinkedList.next) {
    if(iNode.value == searchForValue) {
        resultNode = iNode;
        break;
    }
    resultIndex++;
}

if(resultNode!=null)
    Console.WriteLine($"Found value at index {resultIndex} of {resultNode.value}");
```

I decided to add this alternative answer after so many years because I realized that I didn't actually answer the original poster's question 100% the way they might've wanted it to be answered (maybe they wanted to make their own linked list).
So I am doing it justice now by providing a more "in-tune" answer.

But either will suffice!

Comment: Just realized I did not really generalize my answer (I left my own class names from my project!!!). Also, I mistakenly made "list" be a node when It should've been the list itself. LinkedListNode doesn't have a ".First" property :P So that would've caused an error.

Though the original question asker probably wanted to make his own LinkedList, rather than use the built-in one. But if they don't mind using the built-in, I hope my answer is helpful to them :)

Comment: Why not a foreach?

Comment: @MarcosPereira Because I was assuming they were making their own linked list. So they may or may not have an iterator. Because a foreach would be the obvious thing to do if you were using the built-in Linked List.
And if you are building an iterator for using foreach, you would need this code anyway for the IEnumerator function so you could do a foreach.

Answer (score 5):

For this kind of list, you usually keep a reference to the current node (which starts with the head), and after each iteration, you change the value of that reference to the `next` node. When `currentNode` becomes `null`, you have reached the end of the list, as the last element doesn't have a next element.

Something like this:

```
Node currentNode = head;
while (currentNode != null) {
    // do stuff with currentNode.value
    currentNode = currentNode.Next;
}
```

By the way, the BCL already contains some useful classes for this sort of task:

- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), which internally uses arrays to store elements and provides random access to them
- [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx), which uses the same principle as your custom class.

But maybe you need to do it the way you do for some reason :)

Comment: This is probably for some Abstract Data Structure class that the OP is taking :) When I took it they would not allow me to use Lists haha.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yes, you could be right. But sometimes people coming from other languages or just learning programming don't know about all the useful classes that the BCL already provides :)

Comment: @HanletEscaño right on! It is an algorithm and data structure class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this basic iteration:

```
Node tmp = head;
while (tmp != null)
{
    //do your checking...
    tmp = tmp.next;
}
```